# What are 'panda-esque' data structures to store in DataFrames?

Tags: python, pandas, data-structures

I've heard that pandas doesn't 'deal well' with storing lists or dictionaries in individual cells, however I'm struggling to find more information on *why* this is the case. In many use cases it would be very useful for me to store more complex data structures in a Pandas cell - like a dictionary - how would I do this in a 'panda-esque' manner? Does this apply to all mutable data structures?

Comment: Because you lose any possibility of performing vectorised operations when the dtypes are not scalar values. It has nothing to do with mutable data structures. All you gain is flexibility in retrieving columns and rows but for instance if you wanted to search for a value in a column containing lists, you'd have to iterate over every row and test rather than a simple `df['col'] == some_val`

Comment: Imagine some sort operation you do in pandas on a dictionaries vs similar operation on several dataframes with dictionary elements.

Answer (score 0):

This probably isn't what you're looking for because @EdChum is right.  Very simply, there are very few good reasons to place non-scalar objects into `pd.Series` and `pd.DataFrame` cells.

Consider the dataframe `df`

```
d1 = dict(a=1, b=2, c=3)
d2 = dict(d=1, e=2, f=3)
d3 = dict(g=1, h=2, i=3)
d4 = dict(j=1, k=2, l=3)
d5 = dict(m=1, n=2, o=3)
d6 = dict(p=1, q=2, r=3)

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    A=[d1, d2, d3],
    B=[d4, d5, d6]
))

df

                          A                         B
0  {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}  {'j': 1, 'k': 2, 'l': 3}
1  {'d': 1, 'e': 2, 'f': 3}  {'m': 1, 'n': 2, 'o': 3}
2  {'g': 1, 'h': 2, 'i': 3}  {'p': 1, 'q': 2, 'r': 3}
```

---

You're better off, using embedded dictionaries.

```
d = df.to_dict()

d['A'][0]

{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
```

---

However, if you want to manipulate them row or column-wise, you could write a subclass of `dict` where you define addition

```
from cytoolz.dicttoolz import merge

class dict_(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __add__(self, other):
        return dict_(merge(self, other))
```

Then you could convert values to this new class and...

```
df.applymap(dict_).sum()

A    {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 1, 'e': 2, 'f': ...
B    {'j': 1, 'k': 2, 'l': 3, 'm': 1, 'n': 2, 'o': ...
dtype: object
```

or

```
df.applymap(dict_).sum(1)

0    {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'j': 1, 'k': 2, 'l': 3}
1    {'d': 1, 'e': 2, 'f': 3, 'm': 1, 'n': 2, 'o': 3}
2    {'g': 1, 'h': 2, 'i': 3, 'p': 1, 'q': 2, 'r': 3}
dtype: object
```

Or even get a numpy object array

```
df.applymap(dict_).values.sum()

{'a': 1,
 'b': 2,
 'c': 3,
 'd': 1,
 'e': 2,
 'f': 3,
 'g': 1,
 'h': 2,
 'i': 3,
 'j': 1,
 'k': 2,
 'l': 3,
 'm': 1,
 'n': 2,
 'o': 3,
 'p': 1,
 'q': 2,
 'r': 3}
```

---

That's kinda fun!  Not sure how "Pandas-esque" that is, but I like it.